# XNA: Get an array/list of resources?

Tags: c#, xna

I am currently developing a game using XNA (School project), and I was wondering if there's a way to list all the resources during runtime because my resource files are named ###-Name## and I want to index them on the first 3-digit number.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Would something like this help?

```
public static Dictionary<String, T> LoadContent<T>(this ContentManager contentManager, string contentFolder)
{
   //Load directory info, abort if none
   DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(contentManager.RootDirectory + "\\" + contentFolder);
   if (!dir.Exists)
      throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();
   //Init the resulting list
   Dictionary<String, T> result = new Dictionary<String, T>();

   //Load all files that matches the file filter
   FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
   foreach (FileInfo file in files)
   {
      string key = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);

      result[key] = contentManager.Load<T>(contentManager.RootDirectory + "/" + contentFolder + "/" + key);
   }   
   //Return the result
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of just scanning the content folder :/

Comment: Great stuff!  For anyone struggling to use this I found that for my project I needed to remove "contentManager.RootDirectory +" from the load call because I set the Content.RootDirectory = Content already. Also this method needs to be in a static class to be used.

Comment: Note that this seems to load all the content (thus the name of the method). If you want to just enumerate the items but *not load* them, this might be a little heavy. Also, I don't think there's any way to enumerate the content of a certain type <T> without loading the content. Meh. I suppose an offline step would work well in this scenario.