# XNA Load/Unload logic (contentmanager?)

Tags: c#, xna, content-management-system, monogame

I am trying to make a point-and-click adventure game with XNA, starting off simple. My experience with XNA is about a month old now, know how the classes and inheritance works (basic stuff).

I have a problem where I cannot understand how I should load and unload the textures and game objects in the game, when the player transitions to another level. I've googled this >10 times, but all I find is hard coding while I only understand the basics of unloading yet.

All I want, is transitioning to another level (replacing all the sprites with new ones).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want to load/unload the content on the runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Content Load:

```
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
// This is a texture we can render.
Texture2D myTexture;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("mytexture");
}
```

#### Content Unload:

```
protected override void UnloadContent()
{
    Content.Unload();
}
```

These are the simplest methods of loading and unloading contents. For more information refer to the following link.

- [Adding contents to a game](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203887.aspx)
- [ContentManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.aspx)
- [How do I unload content from the content manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264995/how-do-i-unload-content-from-the-content-manager)
- [XNA game studio LoadContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088331/xna-game-studio-loadcontent)